algorithm to validate complex json data in a table which stores json key value pairs in column ,use it in another table which stores parent child data

1.extract all the key value pairs - suggest option which can be reused (temp table,CTE,or more suitable)


2.write a query which takes one key value at a time and searches for the value in another table using join.


3.create a expected dataset result

I tried using cross apply openjson and got the key value pairs in a temp table but that is not reliable as session gets lost due to network connection as Db server is on EC2 instance.
sql querying also is tough as involving multiple joins and on json column for one key.extracting that one key and then perform join to a table which stores that one key as parent and child’s needs to extracted.
expected dataset has to store child’s information.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Is this a ultimately just a SQL question? Where do the other tags factor in here? It would be super helpful to see what you have already attempted to know where to begin helping.
